# Java Update UI from a Worker Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I am working with JavaFX and I need to somehow update a UI element from a worker thread.

My worker thread is constantly listening, through a socket, for incoming connections. When it detects one, it calls a method updateListOfConnections();

What I want to do is updateListOfConnections is pretty simple:

```
this.deviceList.clear();
this.deviceList.addAll(this.contactManager.getContacts().keySet());

if(this.deviceList.size() > 0){
    updateConnectButtonState(false);
} else {
    updateConnectButtonState(true);
}
```

As you can see, I affect the state of the UI for a couple items here and when I attempt to call updateListOfConnections from my thread, I get an exception.

---

Some possible solutions that I came up with (which are really unideal) are:

I simply have the user manually refresh the deviceList by invoking updateListOfConnections with the press of a button.

Or, have a loop constantly running and when it gets to a certain interval, reset the interval and invoke updateListOfConnections.

---

So my main question is how do I update an UI element from a worker thread in Java with JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**Platform#runLater()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) static method, which runs the specified `Runnable` on the *JavaFX Application Thread*; it could be called from any thread:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    // The code that you want to run on the JavaFX Application Thread
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` to execute code on the main JavaFX thread.

I would however advise you to take a look at JavaFX binding. [LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm)

For instance, in your controller (instantiated from FXML for instance)

```
@FXML private Button aButton;
private final BooleanProperty disableProperty = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();

public init() {
    disableProperty.bind(-- Your observable list here--.isEmpty());
    aButton.disableProperty().bindBidirectional(disableProperty);
```

Comment: What if the socket connection was successful, and it deliberately returned zero contacts?

Comment: @VGR Any updates made to the list you're binding to are reflected in the view automatically. That's the idea of JavaFX bindings.

Comment: What I meant was that an empty list doesn't necessarily indicate the lack of a connection.